# What is this white residu on my bamboo?

Tags: identification, fungus, bamboo

[image]

I was wondering what the white thing on my bamboo leaves is. It's near a fountain so I thought maybe it's tesidu from whatever is in the fountain but now I'm wondering if it could be some kind of mold...

Comment: Are all the leaves affected or just the ones that might catch spray  or  droplets from the fountain? Anything odd beneath the leaves?

Comment: Most of the leafs are affected but they might all be exposed to the fountain droplet. Some have a little white underneath but the underside of the leufs are mostly fine.